# Simulate posterior from a linear mixed model with categorical and continuous variables and their interactions

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, posterior, credible-interval

Currently, I am working on a data set containing isotopic ratios. To understand differences in the ratios I am fitting a linear mixed model in R using the *lme4* package. I am then using the *arm* package ands its *sim()* function to generate the posterior simulations of sigma and beta from the lmerMod object and base my inference on the 95 % Credible Interval of the posterior.

However, while I was able to do this for the model with one response variable in relation to one continuous explaining variable and one categorical explaining variable and an interaction between them, I am struggling to do the same for a model that contains 3 explaining variables (1 continuous and 2 categorical) and two interactions.

This is my data where the factor sex and season have two levels each and size is numeric/continuous.

```
data <- structure(list(response = c(-15.4, -14.3, -14.8, -14.5, -16, 
-13.6, -17.5, -16.1, -16.3, -14.2, -15.7, -15.1, -14.9, -15.2, 
-18.6, -15.4, -15.8, -13.7, -14.3, -15.1, -15.3, -14.3, -15, 
-15.1, -16.2, -14.2, -17.8, -15.8, -16.9, -15.3, -12.5, -15.5, 
-14.6, -15.1, -18.8, -15.4, -16.5, -15.5, -15.8, -15.2, -14.4, 
-14.4, -15.2, -17.4, -15, -15.1, -14.8, -14.2, -15.9, -15.4, 
-15.7, -12.8, -15.4, -13.9, -17.4, -18.6, -16.4, -16.5, -17, 
-17.5, -15.4, -18.4, -19.6, -15.8, -15.2, -14.8, -15.7, -16.4, 
-12.7, -15.9, -17.4, -16.3, -17.4, -16.6, -17, -15.4, -16, -15, 
-16.8, -18, -14.7, -17.8, -15.1, -14.8, -17.2, -16.9, -14.2, 
-19.4, -17.5, -15.6, -15.1, -16.4, -15.2, -17.1, -14.7, -15.1, 
-17.8, -14.9, -15, -14, -15.1, -13.9, -14.2, -14.1, -15, -13.9, 
-16.4, -14.7, -15.4, -14.7, -18.6, -15, -17.4, -15, -18.6, -14.1, 
-16.3, -16, -14.8, -16.7, -14.9, -14.8, -14, -14.6, -15.1, -15.3, 
-14.5, -12.7, -13.2, -12.8, -14.3, -15, -13.6, -15.8, -13.8, 
-14.1, -17.2, -17.7, -17.2, -17.2, -19.8, -15.5), sex = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("F", 
"M"), class = "factor"), season = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("summer", 
"winter"), class = "factor"), size = c(48, 77.2, 77, 87, 52, 
57, 68, 87.8, 99, 98.2, 90, 93.3, 91.6, 103.1, 70.6, 85.2, 93.1, 
88.9, 78.1, 94.4, 101.2, 65.2, 102.1, 90.1, 94, 104.8, 77, 88.3, 
84, 77, 66.8, 79.4, 92, 99.4, 87.2, 91.1, 98.8, 96, 88.3, 93, 
76.1, 96.4, 94.9, 67.1, 42.2, 95, 91.1, 82.4, 50, 94.9, 82, 91.8, 
87.4, 85.8, 82, 95.6, 74.6, 74, 88.5, 108.4, 54.2, 92, 84, 97.4, 
91.2, 97, 72.6, 48.8, 83, 94, 93.9, 91, 92.5, 103.4, 93.1, 88, 
90.3, 88.3, 74.5, 86, 45, 80.2, 86.5, 92.6, 92, 89, 72.5, 82, 
98, 65.4, 83, 105.6, 56.4, 93.7, 53.5, 46.3, 93.5, 48.2, 42.6, 
79.5, 60, 80.2, 76.5, 88, 75.2, 70.8, 78, 83.9, 54.2, 92.1, 90.4, 
101, 70.4, 83, 91.5, 80.3, 73, 78, 68.3, 45, 51.6, 64, 90.5, 
72.5, 85.7, 91.7, 77, 51.9, 73.2, 88.5, 78.4, 78.5, 71, 63.5, 
53, 52, 99.5, 86.1, 92.7, 89, 97.9, 84.8), unique_identifier = structure(c(86L, 
50L, 4L, 16L, 42L, 35L, 14L, 23L, 10L, 18L, 12L, 74L, 13L, 32L, 
29L, 85L, 90L, 30L, 24L, 15L, 8L, 17L, 56L, 13L, 25L, 18L, 36L, 
33L, 38L, 66L, 94L, 19L, 92L, 16L, 49L, 53L, 2L, 6L, 33L, 13L, 
82L, 1L, 6L, 31L, 54L, 32L, 34L, 9L, 52L, 34L, 11L, 48L, 58L, 
64L, 63L, 40L, 20L, 57L, 65L, 43L, 61L, 59L, 129L, 22L, 7L, 32L, 
46L, 69L, 62L, 8L, 67L, 60L, 37L, 45L, 55L, 80L, 91L, 5L, 3L, 
51L, 47L, 83L, 28L, 27L, 60L, 88L, 44L, 95L, 73L, 72L, 77L, 76L, 
39L, 10L, 71L, 89L, 2L, 87L, 70L, 79L, 26L, 68L, 84L, 93L, 119L, 
113L, 122L, 108L, 81L, 21L, 107L, 78L, 117L, 100L, 114L, 116L, 
120L, 118L, 109L, 104L, 75L, 128L, 110L, 105L, 96L, 98L, 41L, 
111L, 123L, 103L, 102L, 99L, 126L, 97L, 115L, 106L, 121L, 124L, 
127L, 112L, 125L, 101L), levels = c("4C4A72220F", "900236000107745", 
"900236000108035", "985121031803315", "985121031803859", "985121031809367", 
"985121031817057", "989001004378368", "989001004378382", "989001004378459", 
"989001004378515", "989001004605135", "989001004605145", "989001004605180", 
"989001004605300", "989001004605331", "989001005924813", "989001005924837", 
"989001005924851", "989001005924856", "989001005924875", "989001005924975", 
"989001005924984", "989001006700493", "989001006700520", "989001006700537", 
"989001006700560", "989001006700567", "989001006700633", "989001006700659", 
"989001006700707", "989001006700794", "989001006700810", "989001006700847", 
"989001006700866", "989001026313143", "989001026313152", "989001026313157", 
"989001026313161", "989001026313172", "989001026313180", "989001026313185", 
"989001026313187", "989001026313193", "989001026313194", "989001026313197", 
"989001026313198", "989001026313200", "989001026313219", "989001026313238", 
"989001026313243", "989001026313255", "989001026313275", "989001026313278", 
"989001026313287", "989001026313302", "989001026313343", "989001026313357", 
"989001026313359", "989001026313369", "989001026313370", "989001026313371", 
"989001026313378", "989001026313388", "989001026313402", "989001026313413", 
"989001026313417", "989001026313424", "989001026313440", "989001026313442", 
"989001026313444", "989001026313449", "989001026313456", "989001026313458", 
"989001026313461", "989001026313464", "989001026313468", "989001026313469", 
"989001026313473", "989001026313486", "989001026313488", "989001026313492", 
"989001026313493", "989001026313495", "989001026313498", "989001026313501", 
"989001026313503", "989001026313510", "989001026313514", "989001026313524", 
"989001026313525", "989001026313529", "989001026313532", "989001026313537", 
"989001026313538", "989001030278216", "989001030278219", "989001030278233", 
"989001030278237", "989001030278261", "989001030278265", "989001030278271", 
"989001030278291", "989001030278298", "989001030278304", "989001030278310", 
"989001030278412", "989001030278413", "989001030278420", "989001030278429", 
"989001030278434", "989001030278435", "989001030278436", "989001030278440", 
"989001030278446", "989001030278456", "989001030278485", "989001030278490", 
"989001030278495", "989001030278533", "989001030278545", "989001030278548", 
"989001030278549", "989001030278551", "989001030278562", "989001030278567", 
"989001030278599", "989001030278610", "NoTag"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-142L), class = "data.frame")
```

I fit the following model:

```
mod <- lme4::lmer(response ~ sex + size + season + sex*size + sex*season + (1|unique_identifier), data = data, REML = F)
```

Now, I use sim() from the *arm" package to generate posterior simulations:

```
nsim <- 5000
bsim <- sim(mod, n.sim = nsim)
```

And now I would like to generate the new data with simulated data for the Credible Intervals. In the case of a simpler model where effect 1 is categorical and effect 2 continuous and the following formula:

```
example <- lme4::lmer(example_response ~ effect_1 + effect_2 + effect_1*effect_2 + (1|unique_identifier), data = ex, REML = F)
```

I can generate new data like this:

```
new <- expand.grid(effect_2= seq(min(floor(ex$effect_2)), max(ceiling(ex$effect_2))),
                                  effect_1 = levels(ex$effect_1))
X <- model.matrix(~effect_1 + effect_2 + effect_1*effect_2, data = new)
fit <- matrix(ncol = nsim, nrow = nrow(new))
for(i in 1:nsim) fit[,i] <- X %*% bsim@fixef[i,]
new$lower <- apply(fit, 1, quantile, prob = 0.025)
new$upper <- apply(fit, 1, quantile, prob = 0.975)
```

And when I want to plot the CrI for effect_2 for the first level of effect_1 I use:

```
polygon(c(new$effect_2[1], rev(new$effect_2[1])),
          c(new$lower[1],rev(new$upper[1])),
          border = NA, col = alpha("grey", .5))
}
```

However, I do not understand how I can apply the last two code snippets above to the more complex model of:

```
mod <- lme4::lmer(response ~ sex + size + season + sex*size + sex*season + (1|unique_identifier), data = data, REML = F)
```

So, my question is: how can I simulate the posterior for size, season and sex above and take the different slopes into account as well through the interactions? And how can I extract the information afterwards to plot the CrI as well?